# Sorting issue with reference type list in python panda

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

I am trying to sort a list (based on a UserInfo class) but I am getting an error- AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns. Although when i am creating a static array (dummy array using some fixed values) then I am not getting this error.

```
class UserInfo:
    def __init__(self,name,id,address):
        self.Name=name
        self.EId=id
        self.Address=address

from rwt import UserInfo
import pandas as pd
class saveuser:
    usertoadd=[]
    def adduser(self,name,id,address):
        obj1=UserInfo(name,id,address)
        obj1.Name=name
        obj1.EId=id
        obj1.Address=address
        saveuser.usertoadd.append(obj1)
    def sortbyname(self):
        labels=['Name','EId','Address']
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([saveuser.usertoadd],columns=labels)
        df.sort_values(by=['Name'], axis =1)
        print(df)
myObj=saveuser()
myObj.adduser("Susheel",1,"Delhi")
myObj.adduser("Kapil",3,"Dehradun")
print("---------------After sort------------------------")
myObj.sortbyname()
```

The expected result the list should be sort by name.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors. List `usertoadd` has 2 `saveuser` objects, and you put it to a list to create a nested list and passed it to `pd.DataFrame.from_records`. This causes error: `AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns`. The `pd.DataFrame.from_records` doesn't know `saveuser` attributes, nor be it able to extract them without you explicitly provide them. You need passing list of `saveuser.__dict__` to `from_records` for it correctly get the dictionary of atributes-values pair.

Next, You didn't save the sorted `df` back to original `df` and you sorted on wrong `axis`. To fix this, you just need to specify additional parameter `inplace=True` and sorted on `axis=0`

You just need to change the function sortbyname(self) as follows:

```
def sortbyname(self):
    labels=['Name','EId','Address']
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([user.__dict__ for user in saveuser.usertoadd], columns=labels)
    df.sort_values(by=['Name'], axis =0, inplace=True)
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
---------------After sort------------------------
      Name  EId   Address
1    Kapil    3  Dehradun
0  Susheel    1     Delhi
```

Comment: Maybe you should drop `axis = 0` because it is default. check out the documentation [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: @lrh09: Yes, I know. My purpose is trying to keep the code changes to minimal and as much as verbose as possible to show errors in code. In this case, 'pd.DataFrame()` constructor works fine, no need using `from_records`, but I still use it to keep the code changes to minimal.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign to df. And I assume you want your name to be from A-Z from top to bottom, so this will do:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Name')
```

or you do

```
df.sort_values(by='Name', inplace = True)
```